Conditional Formatting: Formula is true - XLOOKUP formula applying to just one cell, instead of automatically updating
I'm scratching my head around this. I don't know if what I'm trying is even possible in Excel (2021 version) without VAB.
On one hand, I've got a table like this, called "temario":
enter image description here
On the other hand, I've got a non-table calendar. Each "3A-16" is a subject code, being the cell a FILTER function.
enter image description here
Finally, I've cells in column AF which I will use it as my auxiliary column
I want to format those cells based on the following formula
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(XLOOKUP([calendar_cell];temario![range calendar_cell];[range cells used for formatting]);[aux for conditional formatting]))
For instance,
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(XLOOKUP(I7;temario!$D$2:$D$178;temario!$G$2:$G$178);$AF$4))
Lookup column G containing a text matching any of those in column AF. I've tried this formula without conditional formatting and it works perfectly.
What's wrong then?
When I apply to conditional formatting, it just work in the cell that I set in first place, for instance cell "I7". If I drag it to cell J7, it just keeps referencing to I7 in my formula.
Then, I don't know how to make my lookup formula to dynamically change to the active cell.
Thanks in advance
File: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/j2eux2rkxide72704yc4w/Book3-Copy.xlsx?rlkey=1o4iyqpu5jumcy4saz10rrf5r&st=hjadf5t0&dl=0

It's hard to follow your explanation since your screencaps don't indicate the rows and columns. It would also be useful to see exactly how you apply the conditional format to multiple cells

Hi, I'm sorry I didn't. I can directly upload the file if I find out how to edit the question. Thank you

A screen cap would be better than a dropbox link to a file. Many people won't download files from unknown sources and the link will go dead shortly making the question useless in the future
